# Objects inside lists

Tags: python, class

I have a class with a method. Now, I put that class inside a list. 
When I'm trying to print a method, I do:

```
print(listname[pointer].method)
```

But when I compile it says that objects does not support indexation.

The exact code goes like this:

```
class hero():
    def __init__(self, heroname):
        self.h=heroname

herolist=[]
herolist.append(hero)

print(herolist[0].h)
```

I'm expecting that the code will print the hero name, but it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Sorry, I forgot to show it in the code but outside of the class I did instantiate the object I am trying to call. To be exact, I did something like:

```
heroone=hero()
heroone.h='jude'
```

Comment: Your code has several problems, but it does not give the error you say it does ("does not support indexation").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few problems.  First of all, the name of the initialization method is `__init__` (*two* underscores on each side), not `___init___`.  Second, by appending `hero` you are appending the class itself.  The class itself does not have an `h` attribute.  Only instances of it will have an `h` attribute, because `__init__` is only called when you create an instance.  Third, you forgot the `self` argument in your `__init__` method.  And fourth, you apparently wrote `__init__` to expect a "heroname" argument, but you don't pass any such argument.  (You don't pass any arguments, since you never instantiate the class.)

Try this:

```
class hero():
    def __init__(self, heroname):
        self.h = heroname

herolist=[]
herolist.append(hero('Bob the Hero'))

print(herolist[0].h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using three `_` with `init` method because of which constructor is not called.
two `_` are needed on both side `init`.
To assign name to `h` pass it to init method.
Use CamelCase to namethe class

Below is working code:

```
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, heroname):
        self.h = heroname

herolist=[]

herolist.append(Hero('Dude'))

print(herolist[0].h)
```

Answer (score 0):

You store the class definition, not an instanced objet, which means that `heroname` doesn't have a value. You could write :

```
herolist.append(hero('Achile'))
```

and your example will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:-

```
class Hero():
    def __init__(self, heroname):
        self.h=heroname

herolist=[]
```

Now you can do:

```
h1 = Hero('jude')
herolist.append(h1)
print herolist[0].h
```

or even simpler:

```
herolist.append(Hero('Hero'))
print herolist[0].h
```